# Neo4j Java Rest Binding: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, rest, graph, neo4j

I have a fresh build of neo4j-rest-graphdb-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar . But I'm having trouble right out of the gate.

I have basic/default install of Neo4j running, configured with a valid graph store:

**Neo4j Version**

Graph Database Kernel 1.8.M05

**OS**

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

**Java version**

"1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

**A curl request suggests everything is working nicely:**

```
$ curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/ -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 809
Content-Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Jetty(6.1.25)

{
  "extensions" : {
    "CypherPlugin" : {
      "execute_query" :     "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query"
    },
    "GremlinPlugin" : {
      "execute_script" :     "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script"
    }
  },
  "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
  "reference_node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
  "node_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
  "relationship_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
  "extensions_info" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
  "relationship_types" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
  "batch" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
  "cypher" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
  "neo4j_version" : "1.8.M05-1-ge9cdca9"
```

**But, attempting the following line:**

GraphDatabaseService graph = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/");

**... produces an exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     javax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.<init>(RestAPIFacade.java:265)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.<init>(RestGraphDatabase.java:44)
    at com.tester.api.Neo4j.importer(Neo4j.java:185)
    at com.tester.api.Neo4j.main(Neo4j.java:97)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think it finally all gelled for me:

From the top:

1. upgraded from Maven 2 to Maven 3
2. deleted the ~/.m2/repository to remove any previously-downloaded dependencies
3. then, in the java-rest-binding git repo, I ran `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` to obtain copies of all the dependencies and then added them (the contents of target/dependency folder) to my build path (thanks Peter)
4. using this rest package from source (copying /main/java/org/neo4j to my project's 'org' folder) in Eclipse gave me issues with a missing 'batch request'-type packages for neo4j
5. so, I then ran `mvn package` for another fresh/cloned/checked-out java-rest-binding git repo and copied the resultant .jar (`neo4j-rest-graphdb-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar`) into my project's lib (along with all the dependencies

I have done some preliminary tests and this appears to be working now!

If the above procedure shows my naivete with Maven and you know of a concise guide to avoiding such problems in the future, please share it!

Thanks!

Comment: Quoted from Neo4j Group (from Peter): This works, but you were lucky. Packaging all jars into one might overwrite files that exist with different content under the same location in different ingoing jars, like java service loader files. You don't have these, but be aware if you include the e. g. Kernel and enterprise jars that registers more cache types.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a missing dependency. Have you made sure to include all the dependencies via maven, as stated in https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/master/pom.xml ? You could build the project from source and pull down the deps for it by doing

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

/peter

Comment: Thanks Peter, I tried this, but it did not work (same error).  It builds, then I copy the jar file to my project's lib folder.  Other jars in the build path are:  geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, json-simple-1.1.1.jar, lucene-core-3.5.0.jar, mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar, neo4j-cypher-1.8.M05.jar, neo4j-graph-algo-1.8.M05.jar, neo4j-graph-matching-1.8.M05.jar, neo4j-jmx-1.8.M05.jar, neo4j-kernel-1.8.M05.jar, neo4j-lucene-index-1.8.M05.jar, neo4j-shell-1.8.M05.jar, neo4j-udc-1.8.M05.jar, org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar, scala-library-2.9.1-1.jar, server-api-1.8.M05.jar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that I didn't have jersey. Tried to get all dependencies but didn't get this jar. so the solution can be.. Just download jersey-bundle-1.13-b01.jar.

P.S. : This might not be the best way to resolve it as there could be many dependencies but in this particular scenario it's only jersey which is missing so it works this way :-)